# Running time of HashTable Operations vs HashMap operations?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

What are running times (Big O notaton) for the common operations (get, put, size) on HashTable and HashMap, is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a difference between the asymptotics of `Hashtable` and `HashMap`, and they are the predictable expected amortized `O(1)` for `put` and expected `O(1)` for `get`, assuming that you have a good hash function.

The biggest difference is that `Hashtable` incurs gratuitous overhead synchronizing accesses from concurrent threads, which a) you usually don't need, and b) is done more efficiently by `ConcurrentHashMap`.  You should basically never use `Hashtable` in new code.